# Proof that $\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^N\frac{a_ja_k}{j+k}\ge0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I found this inequality holds:

> Given a sequence of real numbers,
>   $a_1,a_2,...,a_N$, if
>   $$S=\sum_{j,k=1}^N\frac{a_ja_k}{j+k}$$ then $$S\ge0$$

Is it a known result? How is it possible to prove it?

Comment: **Reference:** This is Exercise 10.1 on page 162 of *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class* by J. Michael Steele. The solution is in the back of the book.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Ok, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It strongly reminds me of the [*Hilbert matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), although slightly different. And here is a simple and brutal proof:

$$ S
= \sum_{j,k=1}^{N} a_j a_k \int_{0}^{1} x^{j+k-1} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{1} \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j x^{j-1} \bigg)^2 x \, dx
\geq 0 $$

It is also interesting to notice that the equality holds if and only if $a_1 = \cdots = a_N = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Define matrix $B$ such that $b_{ij}=1/(b_i^2+b_j^2)$. We want to prove that $B$ is positive semi-definite matrix.

By the application of [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), the condition is equivalent to all principal minors of $B$ having nonnegative determinant. By mathematical induction, it is enough to prove that $B$ has nonnegative determinant.

Note that $B$ is [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix) where $x_i=b_i^2,y_i=-b_i^2$. The determinant of $B$ [is given](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Cauchy_Determinant) as$$\frac{\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(x_j-x_i)(y_i-y_j)}{\prod_{1\le i,j\le n}(x_i-y_j)}=\frac{\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(b_j^2-b_i^2)^2}{\prod_{1\le i,j\le n}(b_i^2+b_j^2)}$$and this is obviously nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. I'm also pretty interested in more elementary proof so that even an eighth-or-ninth-grader from high school student could understand it. Is there any way to do without determinants, integrals or any tools of higher (advanced) math? Maybe just using a couple of standard (or not quite standard) inequalities, mathematical induction, algebra, whatever?

Answer (score -1):

In fact, no two real numbers $a_j,a_k$ will produce a negative result regardless of the numbers, so when it's broadened to $N$ numbers it won't be negative since it's just the sum of multiple sets of 2-variable solutions. $$\frac{a_j^2}{2j}+\frac{a_ja_k}{j+k}+\frac{a_k^2}{2k}$$ The above is the expanded version of a 2-variable solution. This function will never be negative as long as $j,k$ are positive; it's irrelevant how large or small they are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't really get your statement about generalizing the case $n=2$: "it won't be negative since it's just the sum of multiple sets of 2-variable solutions." Why so? Could you please expand your answer accordingly so that it is clear that the sum in question can be represented as a sum of (positive) expressions for the 2-variable case.