# Prove that $E\left(\frac{XY}{X^2+Y^2}\right) \geqslant 0$ for i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, contest-math, expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent identically distributed random
>   variables. Prove that
>   $$E\left(\frac{XY}{X^2+Y^2}\right) \geqslant 0.$$

I tried to manipulate with the expression $\dfrac{XY}{X^2+Y^2}$, e.g. tried to rewrite it in the form 
$$\dfrac{XY}{X^2+Y^2} = \dfrac{(X+Y)^2}{4(X^2+Y^2)} - \dfrac{(X-Y)^2}{4(X^2+Y^2)}$$
or even in the form:
$$\dfrac{XY}{X^2+Y^2} = \dfrac{(X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2}{2(X+Y)^2 + 2(X-Y)^2}$$

but it didn't help much.

I am interested to see a proof of this fact or some favorable ideas that may help here.

**Reference:** The problem was proposed in the Kolmogorov Students' Competition in Probability Theory, 2017.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\left(XY\right) \geqslant 0$ is not difficult to show since it equals $\left(\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)\right)^2$

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then  $\mathbb{E}\left(XY\right)  = \mathbb{E}\left(X\right) \mathbb{E}\left(Y\right)$ while if $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed then  $\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)= \mathbb{E}\left(Y\right)$ providing that all these are finite

Comment: The random variables $\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ and $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ are not necessarily independent

Comment: Perhaps one should study the r.v. $\Theta := \arccos \left ( \frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} \right )$.

Comment: @Ramil are you sure this statement is true?

Comment: @amakelov Yes, I was pretty sure when posting the question and now I'm convinced since Sangchul Lee provided a nice and pretty clear proof of this fact -- you can check it out below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a proof:

$$ \Bbb{E}\left[\frac{XY}{X^2+Y^2}\right]
= \Bbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} XY e^{-(X^2+Y^2)t} \, dt \right]
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \Bbb{E}[X e^{-X^2 t}]\Bbb{E}[Y e^{-Y^2 t}] \, dt \geq 0. $$

---

**Addendum.** My observation is that the expectation can be thought as a quadratic form on the space of finite measures. Indeed, if $\mu$ is the common law of $X$ and $Y$, then

$$ \Bbb{E}\left[ \frac{XY}{X^2+Y^2}\right] = \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \, \mu(dx)\mu(dy). $$

So the problem boils down to showing that this form is positive semi-definite. One such way is to find a unitary transformation under which the quadratic form reduces to the usual $2$-norm. Such a transform are often given as integral transformation:

$$ L\mu(t) = \int_{\Bbb{R}} k(t, x) \, \mu(dx). $$

Assuming that $L$ provides such a transformation, it should satisfy

$$ \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \, \mu(dx)\mu(dy)
= \int_{\Bbb{R}} (L\mu(t))^2 \, dt
= \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} \left(\int_{\Bbb{R}} k(t, x)k(t, y) \, dt \right) \mu(dx)\mu(dy). $$

When the dust settles down, it becomes clear what we should hunt: a function $k$ such that

$$ \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} = \int_{\Bbb{R}} k(t, x)k(t, y) \, dt. $$

It is not hard to guess such a function, and indeed my proof uses $k(t, x) = x e^{-x^2 t} \mathbf{1}_{\{t \geq 0\}}$.

Comment: This is really nice! I just want to comment quickly (because this took me a moment to think through) that $\Bbb{E}[X e^{-X^2 t}]$ isn't necessarily nonnegative, but because it's equal to $\Bbb{E}[Y e^{-Y^2 t}]$, the integrand in the final integrand *is* nonnegative.+1

Comment: @πr8, Thank you for the upvote!

Comment: @SangchulLee this is a relly nice approach! Looks like a magic :) But could you please argue why it is legal to move expectation inside the integral? I.e. why for a random variable $X$ and some function $f(x, t)$ the  following should hold $$\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}\left(\int\limits_{a}^b f(X, t)dt\right) = \int\limits_{a}^b \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}(f(X, t))dt$$ (here $a$ and $b$ both can be $-\infty$ or $+\infty$)?

Comment: @Ramil, That's a good point. Assuming that $\Bbb{P}(X = 0) = 0$ (so that the expectation is well-defined), we have $$\Bbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left|XYe^{-(X^2+Y^2)t}\right| \, dt \right] = \Bbb{E}\left[ \frac{|XY|}{X^2+Y^2} \right] \leq \frac{1}{2} $$ and by Fubini's theorem you can still switch the order of integration.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh, I see, thanks. But in this case, we treat to expectation operator as to the integral $\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}(X) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} xp_{X}(x) dx$, don't we? However, $X$ can be discrete or have mixed-type distribution or, say, have something like Cantor function as its distribution function, whatever. Can we rigorously generalize this statement to arbitrary $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @Ramil, Actually, in the probability theory, expectation is simply an integral over the probability space: $$ \Bbb{E}[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \Bbb{P}(d\omega). $$ Note that the notion of types (discrete/continuous/singular continuous) arise only when we begin to compare the law $\Bbb{P}(X \in \cdot)$ of $X$ with the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$. In our cases, however, we are only appealing to the Fubini's theorem and we need not appeal to such notion. Everything can be equally carried out with this abstract integral.

Comment: But if this abstract concept makes you uncomfortable, you can always rely on the representation $$ \Bbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \, dF_X(x) $$ which is again true for any real-valued random variable $X$ having expectation and $F_X(x) = \Bbb{P}(X \leq x)$ is the cdf of $X$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ok, I got it. Thanks for your elaboration, now it's pretty clear! But still, it looks like kind of a magic to me :) Your explanation of how you came up with this solution also looks good to me, and the idea seems to be quite deep, have you known this trick before? It feels like I would never think of this problem in such a way. Is there maybe some books (maybe with some advanced exercises) with a collection of such beautiful ideas that you can recommend me to master my problem-solving skills and enrich my stock of ideas for solving such non-standard problems?

Comment: @Ramil, There are some well-developed theories on positive-definite kernel which I am also not much acquainted with. Probably my intuition for this kind of problem is built from much easier but similar examples like [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024201/proof-that-sum-limits-j-k-1n-fraca-ja-kjk-ge0/2024208#2024208).

Comment: @SangchulLee BTW, the example you referred to is really similar to the problem in question because, actually, just minor changes to your proof there lead to more general inequality $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} \frac{a_ia_j}{b_i^2 + b_j^2} \geqslant 0$. In the current problem, we can use absolutely the same idea: just note that $\Bbb{E}(XYt^{X^2+Y^2-1}) \ge 0$ for $t \ge 0$ and integrate it over $[0, 1]$.