# How to prove $\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} {\frac{x_i x_j}{x_i^2+x_j^2}} \geq 0$ without using integral

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ be nonzero real number. Prove that
$$\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} {\frac{x_i x_j}{x_i^2+x_j^2}} \geq 0.$$

I think this problem by [Prove that $E\left(\frac{XY}{X^2+Y^2}\right) \geqslant 0$ for i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246904/prove-that-e-left-fracxyx2y2-right-geqslant-0-for-i-i-d-x-and-y).
But I want to find proof **without using integral**. How to solve this?

**Edit**: As @qfwfq pointed out, a proof without using integral is given in [Proof that $\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^N\frac{a_ja_k}{j+k}\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024201/proof-that-sum-limits-j-k-1n-fraca-ja-kjk-ge0).
@Ramil's comment there: I'm also pretty interested in more elementary proof so that even an eighth-or-ninth-grader from high school student could understand it. Is there any way to do **without determinants, integrals or any tools of higher (advanced) math**? Maybe just using a couple of standard (or not quite standard) inequalities, mathematical induction, algebra

Comment: Yes, "without using integral" is the difficult part, here.

Comment: A proof not using integrals would be here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024201/proof-that-sum-limits-j-k-1n-fraca-ja-kjk-ge0/2255553#2255553 But it's not easy.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{(x_i^2+x_j^2)t}\, dt=\frac{1}{x_i^2+x_j^2}$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{i,j} \frac{x_i x_j}{x_i^2+x_j^2} =  \sum_{i,j} x_i x_j \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{(x_i^2+x_j^2)t}\, dt $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^0 \sum_{i,j} x_i x_j e^{(x_i^2+x_j^2)t}\, dt $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^0 \left(\sum_{i} x_i  e^{x_i^2t} \right) \left(\sum_{j} x_j  e^{x_j^2t} \right) \, dt $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^0 \left(\sum_{i} x_i  e^{x_i^2t} \right)^2 \, dt \geqslant 0 $$

Comment: Using integrals, it's easy, that's why the OP asked for a proof without integrals.

Comment: Maybe not "easy," but yes, the OP asked whether an other approach was possible.

Comment: @qfwfq you are quite right. I should have read the question more carefully!